# I broke my code and don't know what happened

Tags: php, include

I have this site that was working beautifully. It's been up and running for over a year now, and I just had a request to add one little thing to it.

I added that thing down on line 200 or so of the code, and re-uploaded my php page. I never even touched anything near line 1, but when I refreshed the page I was greeted with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpinclude() in /home/ropepart/public_html/techportal/select.php on line 1

What gives?

Here is the first few lines of my code. Literally starting with line 1. (By the way, I removed that one little thing I added just to make sure that wasn't it, but no, I'm still getting this error.)

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
include("passwords.php");
....code continues on from here....
```

There is no space between the ?php and include. Only a hard enter. When I add a space there I no longer get the error, but my user also doesn't log into a session properly.

Thoughts?

edit:

```html
<h2>Please select the test you'd like to take:</h2>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="hazcomtest.php" class="btn">Hazcom</a></td>
   <td><a href="nfpa70etest.php" class="btn">NFPA 70e</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td><a href="confinedspacetest.php" class="btn">Confined Space</a></td>
   <td><a href="extremetemperaturestest.php" class="btn">Extreme Temperatures</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="ppetest.php" class="btn">Personal Protective Equipment</a></td>
   <td><a href="materialhandlingtest.php" class="btn">Material Handling</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td><a href="bloodbornepathogenstest.php" class="btn">Bloodborne Pathogens</a></td>
   <td><a href="workingregulationsdisclaimer.php" class="btn">Working Regulations</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

So the above is the original code that I had, which I have then returned to. (It's what I currently have.)

I added

```
<tr>    
<td><a href="ladsaf.php" class="btn">ladsaf</a></td>
</tr>
```

Which I have since removed. Literally typed that in, it didn't work, so I deleted it. And now nothing works. So stumped!

And for giggles...here's the entire page! (I guess, it was more like line 50 that I entered code, not 200...sorry about that...)

```html
<?php
session_start();
include("passwords.php");

//this statement will be entered if coming from the login.php page.
if ($_POST["ac"]=="log"){

 //check if submitted username and password exist in $PASSWORD array
 if ($PASSWORD[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"]){
 
  //set various session variables
  $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["username"];
  $_SESSION["firstname"]=$FIRSTNAME[$_POST["username"]];
  $_SESSION["lastname"]=$LASTNAME[$_POST["username"]];
  $_SESSION["email"]=$EMAIL[$_POST["username"]];
 }
 else{

 //if username and password do not exist, set session variable for "incorrect username/password" message and redirect to login.php
  $_SESSION['incorrect'] = "incorrect";
  header('Location: login.php');
 };
};

// check if user is logged in already when they are coming from a random place. If not, redirect to login.php
check_logged();
?>

<html> 
<head>

 <title>Select Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>

<!--Links to all the various tests available on the site-->
<div class="center">

<h2>Hi <?php echo $_SESSION["firstname"].' '.$_SESSION["lastname"].'. You have logged in successfully.';?></h2><br>

<h2>Please select the test you'd like to take:</h2>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="hazcomtest.php" class="btn">Hazcom</a></td>
   <td><a href="nfpa70etest.php" class="btn">NFPA 70e</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td><a href="confinedspacetest.php" class="btn">Confined Space</a></td>
   <td><a href="extremetemperaturestest.php" class="btn">Extreme Temperatures</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="ppetest.php" class="btn">Personal Protective Equipment</a></td>
   <td><a href="materialhandlingtest.php" class="btn">Material Handling</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td><a href="bloodbornepathogenstest.php" class="btn">Bloodborne Pathogens</a></td>
   <td><a href="workingregulationsdisclaimer.php" class="btn">Working Regulations</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
  
<h2>Click this button to check out the Rope Partner Pay Calculator</h2>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><a href="Paycalculator/index.php" class="btn">Pay Calculator</a></td>
  </tr> 
 </table>
 
<h2>Or click this button to logout.</h2>
 <table> 
  <tr>
   <td><a href="logout.php" class="btn">Logout</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove the second `<?php` and remove the first `?>` and what was that code you added?

Comment: Pssssst. https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Thanks @Professor-Zoom Just tried removing the second <?php and the first ?> with no luck.

The code I added was a table row.

<tr> 
   <td><a href="ladsaf.php" class="btn">ladsaf</a></td>
</tr>

Comment: Ok, since there's nothing obviously wrong here, let's try this: give us the code you added on line 200-ish (edit it into the question please). You'd be surprised sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just asked my wife what the hell was wrong. She sent me through all the usual "turn it off and on again" rigmarole. Then she remembered that last time something goofy happened on my PC that we literally copied the code, pasted it into a new file, saved it over the old file, and tried again. (Last time it was with a microsoft word document...)

Anyway, scoffing at her, I tried this ridiculous idea.

Lo and behold, it worked! Yes...yes I'm eating my words now.

Still, don't ask me why this happened. Literally copied and pasted into a new document and that's all. Ugh.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was starting to lean towards. My bet is you had a different character encoding you copied from (i.e. you used something like MS Word, which doesn't do ASCII or UTF-8 by default). Check out Notepad++. it can tell you what encoding your file is in and convert any that don't conform.

Comment: I've been using Notepad++ for as long as I can remember for coding. So I certainly didn't copy it from Word or anything. In this case, I copied it from one notepad++ file directly over to another one. I had also checked that it was UTF-8. I'm still all ears for what it could've been, but I don't think the solutions you just put forth are it either.